# Acer Aspire 7739G can't boot problem

Tags: boot, acer, aspire

I've installed ubuntu 12.04 on Acer Aspire 7739G but i can't boot. After turning on i see acer logo and then black screen with peeping "_" and i tried to reinstall and re-format whole HDD but it doesn't work, any tip what to do?

Answer (score 0):

How long does it blink ? If it beeps longer than 50sec? Can you press `shift key` after the acer screen to bring the grub menu up ? If you can bring up the grub menu press `e` and add acpi=off after `quiet splash` you can learn more here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the nomodeset option. Look here : [Ubuntu Forums Thread 1613132](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132)

If you manage to login with this option, then find and install any additional drivers for your graphic card.